# Foreach with a multidimensional array - Laravel Blade templating

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have the following array result set, I'm trying to loop through each of the results and just echo them out onto the page. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and the blade templating engine

```
Collection {#240 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "desktop"
      "views" => "349"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "mobile"
      "views" => "151"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "tablet"
      "views" => "68"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    $key = 0; $key++; $key < 2;
    {{ $device[$key] }},
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    {{ $device->name }}

    {{ $device->views}}
@endforeach
```

Will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo object properties:

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    {{ $device->name }} has {{ $device->views }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use key then

```
@foreach($devices as $key => $val)
     {{ $device[$key]->name }},
     {{ $device[$key]->views }}
@endforeach
```