# Laravel array result set - Use of undefined constant name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and returning an array result set to my view by using the following

```
return view('home')->with('devices', $devices)
```

I've attempted to loop through my array data by using the following in blade

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    {{ $device[name] }} has
    {{ $device[views] }}
@endforeach
```

Using `$device[name]` throws `Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'`

I've also tried looping through the result like this

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    {{ $device->name }} has
    {{ $device->views }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: lol dude, [you're using my code but you've chosen another guy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976902/foreach-with-a-multidimensional-array-laravel-blade-templating).

Comment: Array keys should be quoted. There are exceptions, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin In that example we both used the word has? Although the mark up is different....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending it like constant not as string. Replace it like this:

```
@foreach($devices as $device)
    {{ $device['name'] }}
    {{ $device['views'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get the same result twice even though I use both keys as a string "name" & "views"

Comment: Try printing devices array like this: `{!! dd($devices) !!}` and print result here.